# Try to multiple huge int but get product of 1

Tags: c

I watched a tutorial which explain int:

[image]

but I just get 1:

```
Enter a:999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
Enter b: 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
a * b = 1

$ ./a.out
Enter a:87999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
Enter b: 89999999999998798774334999999999994378969869869869458639534934578365
product = 1
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What's the source of the program being run?

Comment: do you have a 64bit machine?

Comment: I don't understand much of this question. Surely they tried to explain the integer limits and why 300k * 200k won't fit in `int`?

Comment: That first multiplication yields 60 billion, in most implementation `int` only goes to a bit over 2.1 billion. You can try it with `long` instead of `int` and that might work. Your other examples with `999999999999...` aren't going to fit, however, hence the bad result.

Comment: @EstebanMarin even on 64-bit PCs `int` is a 32-bit type. And 64-bit int can't store such huge numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for you getting 1 instead of -129542144 is that you multiply

999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 and 89999999999998798774334999999999994378969869869869458639534934578365

instead of 300000 and 200000.

Try the following short program you will get the result in the example, -129542144.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 300000;
    int b = 200000;
    printf("%d\n", a*b);
    return 0;
}
```

This is assuming that the datatype is int and that it is at least 32 bits.